I'm attempting to deploy a new lookup field to Salesforce using the Tooling API and running into issues
My ultimate goal is to be able to create multiple new fields, but I'm stuck currently on creating just one. I've been running the JSON through workbench to test and using some examples I've found under different questions here I was able to create a simple text field.
{
"FullName": "Contact.Custom_Field_1__c",
"Metadata" : {
"type" : "Text",
"length" : 255,
"label" : "Custom Field 1",
"required" : false
}
}

Here's what I have currently trying to create a lookup field
{
"FullName": "Contact.Custom_LookupField_1__c",
"Metadata" : {
"type" : "Reference",
"referenceTo" : "Account",
"relationshipName" : "Custom Accounts",
"label" : "Custom Lookup Field 1",
"required" : false
}
}

this gives me the following error though in Workbench
"message: Cannot deserialize instance of complexvalue from VALUE_STRING value Reference or request may be missing a required field at [line:4, column:1]"
Any guidance on what fields may be required that I'm missing, or format issues would be greatly appreciated.

Hi JDaru, can you please provide reference to endpoint you are trying to use? From what I know RestAPI doesn't support metadata work, you need to use either Metadata API or Tooling API.

Thanks for the reply, I wasn't able to get back to this question yesterday it actually turned out to be the "type" value. Everywhere I looked it showed "reference" as the appropriate value. It's "Lookup"....

and you're correct, I updated the tags and the original question. I misspoke and this is a Tooling API question.

I discovered yesterday that despite what I was able to find in documentation the correct value for "type" on a lookup field is "Lookup" and not "reference"
Here's an example of what worked for me.
{
"FullName": "Contact.Custom_LookupField_1__c",
"Metadata" : {
"type" : "Lookup",
"referenceTo" : "Account",
"relationshipName" : "Custom Accounts",
"label" : "Custom Lookup Field 1",
"required" : false
}
}


Can you go into a little more detail here? Which API version are you using in your API call. Including the corrected JSON would also be helpful (yes, even though it is so simple a change).
